# Why is this continued fraction expansion what it is?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

We have to find the continued fraction expansion of the roots of $1553 t^2 + 6014 t + 5820 = 0$, that is, $(\sqrt{14356} - 6014) / 3106$

Simplifying, $(\sqrt{3589}- 3007) / 1553$

The continued fraction expansion is:
-2+ //9, 1, 3, **2, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 13, 9, 1, 9, 1, 118, 1, 9, 1, 9, 13, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2, 4, 29, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 39, 3, 3, 3, 3, 39, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 29, 4**//
where the periodic part is marked in bold (the period has 47 coefficients).

Where is this expansion coming from? I put the sqrt expression into Wolfram Alpha and it gives me a different expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued%20fraction%20%28sqrt%283589%29-3007%29%2F1553) is giving you a negative continued fraction-note that it is $- [1; 1, 8, 1, 3, 2, 2, 9, \dots]$  Your answer key is giving you a positive continued fraction that is added to $-2$.  If you add $3106$ to the numerator to make the value positive, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued%20fraction%20%28sqrt%283589%29-3007%2B3106%29%2F1553) gives $[0; 9, 1, 3, \overline{2, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 13, 9, 1, 9, 1, 118, 1, 9, 1, 9, 13, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1,
9, 2, 2, 4, 29, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 39, 3, 3, 3, 3, 39, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 29, 4}]$ as well

Comment: Your answer key is taking the floor of $-1.89$, getting $-2$, then computing the continued fraction of $+0.11=-1.89-(-2)$  This way the continued fraction part is always positive.  Alpha is computing the continued fraction of $1.89$ and putting a negative sign in front of it, so the continued fraction will evaluate to $0.89$ before you consider the minus sign.

Comment: Are they both technically the same number? I am a little confused how you can have different expansions for the same number.

Comment: Yes, they are the same number with different representations.  It is like your key giving $(-2)+0.11$ and Alpha giving $-(1+0.89)$.  They are equal.  One might be more convenient than the other depending on how you will use it.

Comment: One of the disadvantages of continued fractions is that you can't add, subtract, multiply, or divide them easily.  In decimals, it is easy to see that $0.11+0.89=1, so $-2+0.11=-1.89$.  With continued fractions it is not apparent.